# Name for programming pattern used by Mathematica

Tags: design-patterns, parallel-processing, wolfram-mathematica, speculative-execution, paralleltry

Since Mathematica 7.0, there is ParallelTry function [1] that evaluates multiple functions in parallel, returning the first result received. This is similar to parallelizing a search on a disjoint data structure. Another common use-case is running multiple algorithms for a given problem and waiting for the first result to be returned.

The question is whether there is a good name for this style of computation. I can only think of calling this Eureka style where one of the functions (tasks) finding the result exclaims a eureka!

[1] http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTry.html

Answer (score 1):

This is called "speculative parallelism".   The processor/system runs some parallel thread, speculating it will produce a useful answer; if it does not (for ParallelTry), it is aborted with no effect on the machine state and the non-speculative part (for  ParallelTry, the computation that succeeded first) produces the answer.

Comment: While the need to abort a computation is common, I feel speculative parallelism also has the following associated notion. It requires the undoing effects of a speculated computation if it is discovered that the prediction was wrong and such an execution was unnecessary. There is no such undo notion involved in ParallelTry. Do you agree?

Comment: I agree that speculated and failed thread has its side effects undone; otherwise it wouldn't be "speculative".  I'm under the (mistaken?) impression the ParallelTry aborted threads have their state undone.  (I'm not an expert on this construct.)

Comment: If ParallelTry doesn't abort/undo state changes of the losers, then this scheme is just a signalled event.